# Openvpn client cannot access openvpn server side LAN when using 2 same subnet

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, routing, openvpn

I have the following setup:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Local Area Network 1 (LAN 1) Netmask - 192.168.0.0/24 or 255.255.255.0 |
|   ---------------                                                      |
|  |Default gateway|------------------------------------                 |                          
|  |192.168.0.1    |                                   |                 |
|   ----------------                                   |                 |
|          |                                           |                 |
|   -------------------------------     -------------------------------  |
|  |Ubuntu server (PC2)            |   |Ubuntu server (PC1)            | |
|  |Running as web server          |   |Running OpenVPN server         | |
|  |LAN IP: 192.168.0.5            |   |LAN: 192.168.0.133             | |
|   -------------------------------    |OpenVPN IP: 10.8.0.1           | |
|                                       -------------------------------  |
|                                                                        |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Local Area Network 2 (LAN 2) Netmask - 192.168.0.0/24 or 255.255.255.0 |
|   ---------------                                                      |
|  |Default gateway|------------------------------------                 |                          
|  |192.168.0.1    |                                   |                 |
|   ----------------                                   |                 |
|                                                      |                 |
|                                       -------------------------------  |
|                                      |Iphone client                  | |
|                                      |Connected to openvpn server PC1| |
|                                      |LAN: 192.168.0.5               | |
|                                      |OpenVPN IP: 10.8.0.2           | |
|                                       -------------------------------  |
|                                                                        |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My Iphone in  (LAN 2) is able to connect my openvpn server in my home (LAN 1), but my iphone does not able to access the web server (PC2).

However, when my Iphone client using mobile data and connected to my openvpn server, im able to access the (PC 2).

I have enabled my `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

and 
added `push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"` to server.conf

and this screenshot id my route -n
[route -n](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAF0L.png)

My best guess is the my iphone client confused when using 2 same 192.168.0.0/24 subnet, as it sending traffic the IP address 192.168.0.5 in LAN 2 but not in LAN 1.

How to solve this situation, or force my vpn client route all 192.168.0.0/24 network through openvpn server (PC1) instead of route through LAN 2 default gateway?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Basically two. Either you do SNAT/MASQUERADE for `10.8.0.0/24` (assuming a /24 subnet), or add return route for it (if there's just one LAN subnet, that means use `192.168.1.133` as the gateway of the route) on either whichever hosts the clients need to reach or simply the router (default gateway) of the subnet, so that they know where to send replies to.

Comment: If there are really two LAN subnets you might have to add the return route to the default gateway of the server and make it the gateway for `10.8.0.0/24` on the other LAN's default gateway (if you adopt the return route approach, that is).

Comment: actually my issue similar to this thread https://serverfault.com/questions/418354/how-to-set-up-openvpn-to-let-the-vpn-clients-to-access-all-the-servers-inside-th, and i follow his steps to do the MASQUERADE but i still cant get my openvpn client to access the PC1

Comment: Well maybe try to do tcpdump on PC2 and see if it is reached and how it replies when you access it from iphone. The information you provided is scarce btw. You should provide full `iptables-save` output on PC1, `ip a`/`r` output on both PCs, and maybe also server/client conf of the VPN. Can iphone and PC1 ping each other within the tunnel? How exactly are these three hosts connected in the LAN? Or is the Internet involved?

Comment: @TomYan hey, thanks for reply, i have figured out something and updated the question, pls check it out again, i think is my vpn client confused when using 2 same subnets.

Comment: You haven't exactly given more information. How do the two LANs interconnect? via the Internet? And the fact that the the addresses within each LAN aren't in the same /24 subnet seems kind of off (although possible; without the netmasks the exact situation is unknown).

Comment: But yeah, if the private subnet used by LAN2 and LAN1 (more precisely, the route you push and the subnet route on the device for its own LAN) is the same, then there's a chance that the route is not / cannot be added to the device because of the destination conflict. (But that doesn't *have to* be the case, if for example the route is added to another route table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the problem is due to conflicting destination between the subnet route of LAN2 and the route pushed by the VPN for LAN1, you can try to workaround the conflict by spliting the route being pushed to two halves:

```
route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.128
route 192.168.0.128 255.255.255.128
```

Similar to what the `def1` flag do to the `redirect-gateway` option, this should avoid the conflict and override the existing `192.168.0.0/24` route.

Unfortunately, that still won't allow you to reach the host on LAN1 that has the same IP as your client or its gateway does on LAN2.

To workaround that, you can use another subnet (e.g. `10.9.0.0/24`) to "represent" for `192.168.0.0/24` of LAN1 on LAN2, by using `NETMAP` of iptables on the VPN server (and push route for it):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.9.0.0/24 -j NETMAP --to 192.168.0.0/24
```

Comment: After pushed these 2 routes and restart the openvpn server, i still cant get it works...I think some configuration should be make on my Iphone, because my iphone is pinging 192.168.0.5 in the LAN 2 but not in LAN 1, thats why it cannot reach the PC2, is there possible force my iphone openvpn client route all traffic through the openvpn server in LAN 1?

Comment: That's exactly what `route` does.

Comment: Ok, sorry currently my PC2's IP address has changed to 192.168.0.162 due to ddns, so i think this is the reason why the routes does not works, so what should i do now?

Comment: Can you please provide the exact netmasks of both LANs? I cannot even tell what route(s) should be used exactly because of that.

Comment: Or maybe you should just push `redirect-gateway` so that all (or as much as possible) traffics are routed into the tunnel.

Comment: ok, i updated the question with netmasks for both LANs

Comment: just now i checked my question, i have a typo in the PC 1's IP address and i have updated it, after i push "redirect-gateway", i cannot ping my PC 1, however if i push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0", my iphone is able to ping my PC 1

Comment: What about `redirect-gateway block-local`? And what about PC2? All of a sudden you talk about PC1 (and haven't even mentioned which IP)

Comment: For the record, I was just testing the answer myself, and I confirmed that the route conflict does occur on my ipad and the workaround seems to work as well (I only checked whether the split routes override the existing equivalence so that "LAN traffics" are routed into the tunnel, with traceroute)

Comment: My apologies sir, finally i figure out why is the exact problem, i updated all the latest IP for all devices, currently PC 2 in LAN 1 has IP address 192.168.0.5, and my IPhone has local IP address of 192.168.0.5 (due to DHCP server) which same as PC2 in LAN 1, thats why and how the conflict happened, is there a soolution for it?

Comment: Forget about `redirect-gateway`, it won't help routing LAN traffics into the tunnel. So just use the answer and remember to reconnect to the server after the server has been restarted (so that you get the pushed routes).

Comment: If you really need to access host that has the same IP as you or your gateway on the other LAN, the only workaround I can think of is DNAT (or even NETMAP for the whole subnet) of iptables, such that you simply use another private IP/subnet to represent it.

Comment: Ok, I think the problem has been solved, so thank you for your help! thank you very much!